# Solr Sunspot keywords search two different formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I was trying to debug a query defined in two different types at two different places:

```
UserQuestion.search do 
  keywords "different" do
    fields :question, :answer_text
  end
end
```

And

```
UserQuestion.search do 
  keywords "different" do
    fields :question
    fields :answer_text
  end
end
```

So i want to ask whether pratically is there any difference between these two queries, as both of these lead to the same Sunspot::Search Object:

```
`<Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:UserQuestion"], :q=>"different", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"question_text answer_text_text", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>0, :rows=>30}>`
```

Thank in advance